# Inherit Forms in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, forms, inheritance, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to inherit one form into another in VB (in order to make loading a database used in more than one form more efficient). I've done this with one form simply by inserting `Inherits Menu` at the top. However it seems like all the other forms won't work like this - I'm getting the error
"Base class 'Form' specified for class 'Edit' cannot be different from the base class 'Menu' of one of its other partial types." This would suggest to me that there's some difference between all the other forms and the Menu & other working one, but as far as I remember they were all created the same way (going into the Project section on the toolbar and selecting 'Add Windows Form', and going into the 'Designer.vb' files for each form, they seem to be identical. [This is for my A-Level project so naturally I'm not exactly that aware of all the technicalities.]

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, and .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586, and I'd be happy to give any other required.

https://ibb.co/iDg6i5

https://ibb.co/gBmHqk

Comment: `This is for my A-Level project so naturally I'm not exactly that aware of all the technicalities.` - So you are a student; do you understand what the `Partial Class Edit` file that you show in your attached image with is and its relation to the code file where you performed `inserting Inherits Menu`?

Comment: @TnTinMn No, not really. From what I can tell it seems to be a way of stating that the designer file is a part the same class as the form's code?

Comment: That is correct, but did it occur to you to look up the keyword `Partial` in the documentation to find out more information and confirm your supposition?  Also research the `Inherits` keyword to learn about the constraints on class inheritance.  The error message is explicit and very clear as to what the problem is.  Can you not reason out the corrective action you need to take?

Comment: For future reference, add a new inherited form via the Project Menu->Add Item->Inherited Form template wizard to avoid this issue.

Comment: @TnTinMn I think I see what you're trying to say (Or at least I've changed it to what I think you're trying to say and it's working). The Public class is trying to inherit from Menu, meanwhile the Partial class is inheriting System.Windows.Forms.Form (or, basically the class for forms). Since it can't inherit two different classes, it's throwing an error. Thanks for the help, and thanks for trying to get me to understand it as well!